# Interface communicates between classes

Tags: c#, oop, interface

Is it right to say that interface communicates between two classes? Like it can send information from class B to class C? both classes inherits same interface.

this example I read

> let’s take your “hand” as an example. The “hand” is a class. Your body has two objects of the type "hand", named "left hand" and "right hand". Their main functions are controlled or managed by a set of electrical signals sent through your shoulders (through an interface). So the shoulder is an interface that your body uses to interact with your hands. The hand is a well-architected class. The hand is being reused to create the left hand and the right hand by slightly changing the properties of it.

this only specifies that interface control or manages class, I agree with this point but somehow I came to know that interface can transfer data from one class to another, So is it correct if we define interface like this or **say that we use interface for this purpose**

> Interface creates communication between two classes, for example Interface Iabc inherited in ClassA and ClassB then it can send information of ClassA to ClassB.

```
public interface  Interface1
{
    void  Method1(string msg);
     void Method2(string msg1 ,string msg2);
}
 public static class  HelperClass
 {
     public static void Method1(Interface1 obj ,string msg)
     {
         obj.Method1(msg);
     }

     public static void Method2(Interface1 obj,string msg1, string msg2)
     {
         obj.Method2(msg1,msg2);
     }
 }
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var Car = new Vehcile();
        var HS = new Person();
        Car.per= "Car Clss";
        HS.per = "HS Clss";
        HelperClass.Method1(Car, Car.per);
        HelperClass.Method1(HS, HS.per);
        HelperClass.Method2(Car, Car.per, HS.per);
        HelperClass.Method2(HS, HS.per, Car.per);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

     public class Person : Interface1
 {

    public String per;

     void Interface1.Method1(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    void Interface1.Method2(string msg1, string msg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Person Class" + msg1 + " " + msg2);
    }
}

 class Vehcile : Interface1
{
    public String per;

     void Interface1.Method1(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
    }

    void Interface1.Method2(string msg1, string msg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vehcile Class" + msg1 + " " + msg2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it right to say that interface communicates between two classes?

I wouldn't define an interface as such. I would look at an interface like a binding contract. The contract states: *"Anyone implementing this interface, must be able to do any action defined by the contract."*

For example:

```
public interface IHand
{
    void Shake(IHand otherHand);
}

public class Hand : IHand
{
    public void Shake(IHand otherHand)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Shook the other hand");
    }
}
```

`IHand` is an interface, and it declares a method called `Shake`, which receives another object of the `IHand`. Any class which implements our interface must provide a method called `Shake`, which does something.

In this particular example, our `Hand` class writes out to the console each time it shakes another hand.

Through interfaces, we can create **abstractions**. Meaning, instead of depending on a concrete class (such as `Hand`), we can depend on the **contract only**. This means, that any object that implements `IHand` is fine with us, because it is guaranteed that he'll have a `Shake` method which we can invoke. What happens inside the `Shake` method is beyond us, and we usually don't really care.